# Удаление файла ранее добавленного в архив

Tags: php, zip

Создаю zip архив на сервере вот таким способом

```
$zip = new ZipArchive; //создаем архив
$zip->open('usr_img/'.$id.'.zip', ZipArchive::CREATE); //создаем архив
$img = 'img2.jpg'; //имя файла картинки которой будем добавлять в zip
file_put_contents($img, file_get_contents(www.ru/img.jpg)); //скачиваем картинку  
$zip->addFile($img); //добавляем картинку в zip
unlink($img); //удаляем скаченную с др сервера картинку
$zip->close(); //сохраняем архив
```

и добавляю в него картинку с другого сервера.
как мне сделать так что бы `unlink()` вызывался только тогда когда картинка в архиве а то она удаляется раньше чем попадает в `zip`????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
...
$zip->close(); //сохраняем архив
unlink($img); //удаляем скаченную с др сервера картинку
```